# Finding the position of x in an array of unknown length

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, sorting, find

Given an infinite array (unknown array length) and there are n elements of integer sorted in this infinite array. The n (the number of sorted element) is unknown. Find the position of an integer i in this infinite array in log n time.

Comment: infinite array != unknown array length

Comment: The answer to the question is Binary Tree

Comment: Probably algorithm analysis class

Comment: infinite array IS unknown length because you will never know the length of array. I know BT is part of the solution but it's not the complete solution.

Answer (score 4):

log n means dividing the array by 2 all the time until you find it, as in binary search... so you need to know the value of n.

C# code:

The code to call your function:

```
int position = findInteger(array, 0, searchedValue);
```

The function:

```
public int findInteger(int[] array, int position, int searchValue)
{
    if(array[position] = searchValue)
        return position;
    else if (array[position] > searchValue)
        position = position / 2;
    else // array[position] < searchValue
        position = (array.Count() + position)/2;
    findInteger(array, position, searchValue);
}
```

Comment: I edited the answer cause I sent it before it was complete by accident

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that but what if there are duplicates. I.e. there is a million 0s in the beginning of the array. And the search value was 10 then which 10 come after a million of zeros so it cant never find it because it will look from 0 to 10. Rather than focusing on finding the index of x. how can i find the how many sorted elements there are?

Answer (score 2):

From the problem statement it appears that there is an array A of indefinite length, of which at least n entries exist and are in sorted order.  We will suppose the first n entries are positive integers in ascending order and that accessing A[j] returns nil if j >= n.  At the outset, n is unknown.  Given i, the problem is to determine j such that A[j] == i (or if no such `j<n` exists, return nil).

1. Set k=0, L=1.
2. While true, do step 3.
3. Set k = L and L = 2*L.  If A[L] is nil break to step 4. If A[L] > i break to step 5.  Else continue (in the while loop of step 2).
4. Now `k < n < L`.  Do a binary search in A[k:L] to find last non-nil entry A[n-1]; set L=n-1; then go to step 5.
5. Now A[L] >= i.  Do a binary search in A[k:L] to find i. Return its index if found, else return nil.

To see that the stated method is  O(ln n) bounded, note that it uses at most `2*lg(n)` steps to find n (or an L such that A[L] > i), and then  at most `lg(n)` steps to find i in A[k:L], where lg(n) = ln(n)/ln(2).

If you assume that accessing A[j] does not return nil when j >= n, but instead returns a “random number”, this approach breaks down; for one thing, it might find A[j] == i but with j > n; for another, the O(ln n) time bound may not hold, or will hold only probabilistically; the algorithm would need to be restated to detect decreases in the A[L] value sequence; and if A is such that A[n+1] > A[n] > A[n-1], then n cannot be determined anyway.